# How to Round Up to the nearest 15 minutes in PHP

Tags: php

I have built a clocking in and clocking out program and i am recording everything fine but i need the times to be rounded up to the next 15 minutes.

I am currently using the below code which would sometimes round up sometimes round down.

```
// Round Time to Next 15 mins
$CurrentTime = date('H:i:s');
$CurrentTime = strtotime($CurrentTime);
$precision = 60 * 15;
$NewTime = date('H:i:s', round($CurrentTime / $precision) * $precision);
```

It doesnt matter what the time is, it just always has to jump to the next 15 minutes (i.e. Quarter Past, Half Past, Quarter Too, On the Clock)

Comment: do you want to round up or up and down?

Comment: Hi, i need to round up.

Comment: To always round up you can use [ceil](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

Comment: @RolandStarke or he is using an array with [1 => 60, 2 => 45, 3 => 30, 4 => 15] and checking the minutes for the < xD